# How lazy is the Snowflake SQL compiler and execution?

Tags: sql, testing, exception, optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I rely on Snowflake's lazy evaluation for testing and exception throwing?

Are CTEs lazily evaluated?

Is this documented?

(related question: [Assertions in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737596/assertions-in-snowflake))

Comment: You're mis construing the processes involved.  SQL isn't executed, it's essentially compiled as you say, in to an execution plan *(it's not quite the same as compiling; SQL is not imperative, it's a declarative language, you declare the problem, the DBMS is free to solve it how it likes)*.  Only when that plan is executed do these errors materialise.  If you write a query with code branches that can never be executed, those branches don't make it in to the plan.  If the plan has no divide by zeros in it, regardless of whether the SQL statement did, no divide by zero error will ever get thrown.

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie for the feedback. I put this out there especially to get other's thoughts on these findings.

Comment: Btw @MatBailie - when I run an `EXPLAIN` for the extreme laziness example, the plan does show an `UNION_ALL(1, 1 / 0)`

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to share my own experiments on this regard. Lazy evaluation is very useful for optimization purposes, and also for testing. I couldn't find documentation promising this behavior, so these experiments help determine current behavior

### Throwing exceptions for tests

These potential division by 0 exceptions are not thrown:

```sql
select coalesce(1, 1/0), iff(true, 1, 1/0);
```

This is very useful when writing a sql script to verify results. For example, to verify if a query brings back 3 rows or throw an exception:

```sql
select iff(count(*)=3, 1, 1/0)
from (
    select * from values(1),(2),(3)
);
```

### CTE optimization

Let's find out if Snowflake optimizes CTEs, or if they get evaluated no matter what:

```sql
with oh_no as (
  select 1/0 oh_no
), fine as (
  select 1 fine
)

select *
from fine
;
```

The results are good: That CTE doesn't throw an exception, as it's not evaluated as it's not needed.

### Extreme laziness

This is an interesting one:

```sql
with oh_no as (
  select 1/0 oh_no
), fine as (
  select 1 fine
)

select *
from (
    select * from fine
    union all 
    select * from oh_no
)
limit 1
;
```

In theory an exception should be thrown out of the `union`. But Snowflake sees that the `LIMIT 1` has been evaluated, and it doesn't waste time processing further rows.

This means the same query might throw errors depending on the order in which rows are processed, and the errors won't be thrown if processing an initial number of rows satisfies the query requirements.

### But all these examples are constants?

As @MatBailie notes, all of these examples are constant so they could be optimized before being executed.

Let me add this example for testing the results of a query over an actual table:

```sql
select iff(count(*)=7, 1, 1/0)
from (
    select *
    from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf001.customer
    where c_phone like '18-8%'
);
```

The exception is not thrown, as the table has exactly 7 records that match the condition. Good.

Same for the extreme laziness example, with actual data:

```sql
with oh_no as (
    select 1/0 oh_no
), fine as (
    select c_custkey
    from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf001.customer
    where c_phone like '18-8%'
    limit 1
)

select *
from (
    select * from fine
    union all 
    select * from oh_no
)
limit 1
;
```

Comment: These examples are also purely based on literal values; there are no unknowns at 'compile time'.  Essentially, the last query can be algebraically reduced to `SELECT 1 fine`, before even finalising the plan.  Were you to have `fine AS (SELECT 1 fine FROM some_table)` there would be an unknown number of rows in `fine`.  As `fine` could therefore be empty, the drastic simplification would not be valid.  This would allow the `oh_no` to make it's way in to the plan, and yield different behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie! I added an example testing with actual data.

Comment: Obviously a bit past the initial question but I'm curious as to if you could use a snowflake-esque tryCatch() wrapper like: `select tryCatch(iff(1=2, true, 1/0), 'ERROR: 1 does not equal 2')`  to stop the query and elegantly handle the error instead of `[22012][100051] Division by zero` error

Comment: @ReidWilliams I like this assert() UDF solution for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737596/assertions-in-snowflake

Comment: I am rather sure some things are defined by the ANSI SQL spec like COALESCE not evaluation order. Which could be classified as lazy, where-as snowflake is anti-lazy (agressive) in it's JSON handling and will execute a TO_NUMBER before the where clauses (at times/conditions) thus violating ANSI SQL, because it's faster, and you "can" flip to the TRY_TO_NUMBER to avoid the exceptions.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim - that's interesting! Do you have some examples to share? (in an additional answer?)